# Imagenes ajustada a titulo flexbox

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de ajustar unas imagenes/logos a sus respectivos nombres, uso flexbox y scss, sin embargo a pesar de haberlo dividido todo en contenedores div para tratar de centrarlo lo mejor posible, no logro concordar la imagen que corresponde con su texto, quedando uno de ellos o descentrado o no ajustado del todo. Adjunto el correspondiente codigo a continuación

Mi idea es que cada nombre y logo, este ajustado en su lugar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.seccion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  &__sobreMi {
    width: 400px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-right: 100px;

    // &__titulo {
    //   transition: transform 0.5s;
    //   background-image: linear-gradient(currentColor, currentColor);
    //   background-position: 0% 100%;
    //   background-repeat: no-repeat;
    //   background-size: 0% 2px;
    //   transition: background-size 0.3s;
    // }
  }

  &__tecnologias {
    &__columna1 {
      display: flex;
    }
    &__nombre1 {
      display: flex;

    }

    &__columna2 {
      display: flex;
    }
    &__nombre2 {
      display: flex;
    }

    ul li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    img {
      width: 90px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="seccion">
  <div class="seccion__sobreMi">
    <h1 class="seccion__titulo">Sobre mi</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lectus
      risus, condimentum sed erat eget, consequat laoreet lorem. Vivamus pretium
      turpis mattis ligula bibendum eleifend non non lacus. Donec et ex maximus
      nisl ornare finibus ac ac tellus. Suspendisse tincidunt leo at sem
      scelerisque vehicula.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="seccion__tecnologias">
    <ul>
      <div class="seccion__tecnologias__nombre1">
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>ANGULAR</li>
      </div>
      <div class="seccion__tecnologias__columna1">
        <li><img src="../../assets/img/html.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="../../assets/img/css.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="../../assets/img/angular.png" /></li>
      </div>
      <div class="seccion__tecnologias__nombre2">
        <li>TYPESCRIPT</li>
        <li>JAVA</li>
        <li>MYSQL</li>
      </div>
      <div class="seccion__tecnologias__columna2">
        <li><img src="../../assets/img/typescript.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="../../assets/img/java.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="../../assets/img/mysql.png" /></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Favor coloca el CSS generado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor es que ocuparas [GRID](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) por sobre flex, ya que justamente lo que estás haciendo es una grilla

Además me parece que lo razonable es que un contenedor envuelva tanto el titulo como la imagen, no separados como tú lo tienes. Si tu quisieras agregar otra imagen sería un lio, de igual manera hacerlo responsivo, por ejemplo que se vea una sola columna en telefonos.

Ejemplo

```css
.seccion__tecnologias{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px,1fr));
  justify-items:center;
}

.seccion__tecnologias h3{
 text-align:center;
}
img{
  width: 140px;
  height:140px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="seccion__tecnologias">

  <div>
    <h3>HTML</h3>
    <img src="../../assets/img/html.png" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h3>CSS</h3>
    <img src="../../assets/img/css.png" />
  </div>
  
  
  <div>
    <h3>ANGULAR</h3>
    <img src="../../assets/img/angular.png" />
  </div>
  
  
  <div>
    <h3>TYPESCRIPT</h3>
    <img src="../../assets/img/typescript.png" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h3>JAVA</h3>
    <img src="../../assets/img/java.png" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h3>MYSQL</h3>
    <img src="../../assets/img/mysql.png" />
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Yo coloqué:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px,1fr));` Esto lo hace responsivo automáticamente, generando una columna que tiene como mínimo 220px

Si tú quieres mantener la grilla como 3x2, simplemente pones

`grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`